# Show that any two n-simplexes are homeomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplex

This seems like a very basic result in Algebraic Topology (e.g. it shows up as exercise 0.1.1.1, the very first one, in John Stillwell's "Classical Topology and Combinatorial Group Theory").

I am interested in having a full-blown proof, something that surprisingly I wasn't able to find that easily online to compare to.

Intuitively, its clear that the mapping we're interested in can be found by representing every point using the barycentric co-ordinates in each of the respective n-simplexes and then simply defining the homeomorphism to be the mapping transforming points by maintaining the convex combination of weights (all non-negative, summing to one) but switching out the "basis vectors" corresponding to the vertices of the n-simplex, e.g.:

$$ x = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} w_i\vec{p_i} \rightarrow f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} w_i\vec{q_i}$$

What I'm looking for is to have full chain of reasoning why this is indeed a homeomorphism (e.g. a continuous mapping with a continuous inverse).

One line of reasoning I came up with that seems a bit more convoluted than should be called for and makes use of a generous amount of point-set toplogy goes like this:

1. we can represent any point in the "standard" n-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by identifying the vertices of the n-simplex with the basis vectors $\vec{e_i}$ and then each point in the n-simplex is simply represented as $\vec{w} = (w_{1}, w_{2}, ..., w_{n+1})$, with the w's corresponding to the non-negative weights summing to 1.
2. We can define a mapping from this standard n-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ to any other n-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (or $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ or above..) by $f(\vec{w}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}w_i\vec{p_i}$ (the p vectors representing the vertices of the n-simplex we are mapping into)
3. Given that this is a linear transformation (e.g. can be represented as $f(\vec{w}) = P\vec{w}$ where P is the matrix having the $\vec{p_i}$ vectors as columns), it is also continuous, and it is easy to see that it is also injective (keeping in mind we limit the $w_i$'s to be non-negative and sum to one), and so we have a result in topology that tells us this is a homeomorphism (See Corollary [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Bijection_from_Compact_to_Hausdorff_is_Homeomorphism)).
4. we can now compose the inverse of this mapping (e.g. from one n-simplex P to the standard n-simplex), with the (forward) mapping from the standard n-simplex to the other n-simplex Q, and get the desired homeomorphism (since composition of homeomorphisms [results in a homeomorphism](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Composite_of_Homeomorphisms_is_Homeomorphism)).

Is this right? are there much simpler proofs from basic linear algebra/analysis that are usually used here otherwise?

Comment: Perhaps you would be happy with [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system), which amount to taking linear combinations of the vertex points of an $n$-simplex.  So the correspondence between simplices is quite evident, given any choice of correspondence on their vertex points.

Comment: I think you've done a careful job of addressing the exercise, examining what is required to show barycentric coordinates give a homeomorphism of the standard $n$-simplex and an arbitrary $n$-simplex.  The mapping is the restriction of a linear transformation to a subspace, so it retains continuity, etc.  One can drill down into the details of why the mapping is injective and surjective, but I think the purpose of the exercise is to give you confidence that this machinery makes sense and works "as intended".

Comment: What is the precise definition of an $n$-simplex?

Comment: A more general result holds. If $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is any compact covex subset with nonempty interior, then there is a homeomorphism of pairs $(D^{n+1},S^n)\xrightarrow\cong(K,\partial K)$.

Comment: @Tyrone But that is not trivial.